# Coiling of flexible ropes (nonlinear BVP of ODEs with 10 unknown functions and 2 parameters)

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, numerics, boundary-conditions

I want to solve this ODEs with `NDSolve`, but it fails. The $F$(`F`), $\gamma$ (`γ`) is the given and the $\Omega$ (`Ω`), $l$ (`l`) will be determined with boundary conditions. (Only $x$ (`x`), $y$ (`y`),$z$ (`z`), $q_0$ (`q0`), $q_1$ (`q1`), $q_2$ (`q2`), $q_3$(`q3`), $n^{(3)}$ (`n`), $\kappa^{(1)}$ (`k1`), $\kappa^{(2)}$ (`k2`) are the functions of $s$ (`s`). ) But it doesn't work.

The problem is from the article [*Coiling of flexible ropes* (Proc. R. Soc. Lond. A (1996) 452,1679-1694)](https://doi.org/10.1098/rspa.1996.0089), in the article software AUTO is used to solve the equation with continuation method, but I have tried it using matlab `bvp4c`, it fails. So can it be solved with *Mathematica*?

Thanks a lot!

```
Clear["`*"]
L = ({
    {q1[s]^2 - q2[s]^2 - q3[s]^2 + q0[s]^2, 
     2 (q1[s] q2[s] + q0[s] q3[s]), 2 (q1[s] q3[s] - q0[s] q2[s])},
    {2 (q1[s] q2[s] - q0[s] q3[s]), -q1[s]^2 + q2[s]^2 - q3[s]^2 + 
      q0[s]^2, 2 (q2[s] q3[s] + q0[s] q1[s])},
    {2 (q1[s] q3[s] + q0[s] q2[s]), 
     2 (q2[s] q3[s] - q0[s] q1[s]), -q1[s]^2 - q2[s]^2 + q3[s]^2 + 
      q0[s]^2}
   });
l11 = L[[1, 1]]; l12 = L[[1, 2]]; l13 = L[[1, 3]]; l21 = 
 L[[2, 1]]; l22 = L[[2, 2]]; l23 = L[[2, 3]]; l31 = L[[3, 1]]; l32 = 
 L[[3, 2]]; l33 = L[[3, 3]];
equ = {q1'[s] == l/2 (q0[s] k1[s] - q3[s] k2[s]),
   q2'[s] == l/2 (q3[s] k1[s] + q0[s] k2[s]),
   q3'[s] == l/2 (-q2[s] k1[s] + q1[s] k2[s]),
   q0'[s] == l/2 (-q1[s] k1[s] - q2[s] k2[s]),
   x'[s] == 2 l (q1[s] q3[s] + q0[s] q2[s]),
   y'[s] == 2 l (q2[s] q3[s] + q0[s] q1[s]),
   z'[s] == l (-q1[s]^2 - q2[s]^2 + q3[s]^2 + q0[s]^2),
   n'[s] == -(k1[s]*k1'[s] + k2[s]*k2'[s]) + 
     l*γ*(l33 + F*Ω^2*(x[s]*l31 + y[s]*l32)),
   k1''[s] == 
    l^2 (n[s]*k1[s] + γ*l23 + 
       F*γ*(k1[s] - 
          2*Ω*
           l13 + Ω^2*(x[s]*l21 + y[s]*l22))),
   k2''[s] == 
    l^2 (n[s]*k2[s] - γ*l23 + 
       F*γ*(k2[s] - 
          2*Ω*
           l23 - Ω^2*(x[s]*l11 + y[s]*l12)))};
bound = {z[1] == 1, q1[1] == 0, q2[1] == 0, q1[0] == -0.5, 
   q2[0] == 0.5, q3[0] == 0.5, q0[0] == 0.5, y[0] == 0, z[0] == 0, 
   k2[0] == 0, k1[0]*x[0] == -1, Ω x[0] == 1};
Length[bound]
F = 0.1; γ = 10;

sol = ParametricNDSolve[
   equ~Join~bound, {x, y, z, q0, q1, q2, q3, n, k1, k2}, {s, 0, 
    1}, {Ω, l}];
FindRoot[{Evaluate[x[Ω, l][1] /. sol], 
  Evaluate[y[Ω, l][1] /. sol]}, {{l, 
   1.5}, {Ω, 2.3}}]
```

Equations are as follows ($l_{11} \sim l_{33}$ are the elements of matrix $L$):

[image]

matlab code:

```matlab
clear;clc;
Omega =1;
len=pi/2;
n=100;
para=[0 1]; % F gamma
lambda=[Omega,len];
options = bvpset('NMax',n,'RelTol',1e-4);
solinit = bvpinit(linspace(0,1,n),@(s) maha4init(s));
sol = bvp5c(@(s,y) maha4ode(s,y,para), @maha4bc, solinit,options);
for i=1:20
para(2)=para(2)+0.00001*i;
options = bvpset('NMax',n,'RelTol',1e-4,'FJacobian',@(s,y) mahajac(s,y,para),'BCJacobian',@(ya,yb)  mahabcjac(ya,yb));
options = bvpset('NMax',n,'RelTol',1e-4,'FJacobian',@(s,y) mahajac(s,y,para));
sol = bvp4c(@(s,y) maha4ode(s,y,para), @maha4bc, sol,options);
lambda=[Omega,len];
fprintf('Omega  %7.3f.\n  len %7.3f.\n x0 %7.3f.\n ',sol.y(13),sol.y(14),1/sol.y(5,1));
subplot(2,10,i)
R=sol.y(5,1);
theta=linspace(0,2.*pi,n);
plot3(sol.y(5,:),sol.y(6,:),sol.y(7,:),'LineWidth',3);
hold on
plot3(R.*cos(theta),R.*sin(theta),0.*ones(1,n),'b--','LineWidth',2);

end

fprintf('Omega  %7.3f.\n  1/x0 %7.3f.\n len %7.3f.\n ',sol.parameters(1),1/sol.y(5,1),sol.parameters(2));


% sol.y(1,:) 
% sol.y(2,:) 
% sol.y(3,:) 
% sol.y(4,:) 
% sol.y(5,:) 
% sol.y(6,:) 
% sol.y(7,:) 
% sol.y(8,:) 
% sol.y(9,:) 
% sol.y(10,:) 
% sol.y(11,:) 
% sol.y(12,:) 


% figure(1)
% for i=1:12
% subplot(3,4,i)
% plot(sol.x,sol.y(i,:))
% end
% 
% 
% figure()
% R=sol.y(5,1);
% theta=linspace(0,2.*pi,n);
% plot3(sol.y(5,:),sol.y(6,:),sol.y(7,:),'LineWidth',3);
% hold on
% plot3(R.*cos(theta),R.*sin(theta),0.*ones(1,n),'b--','LineWidth',2);
% 
% 

%% define functions and bounds
% y [ks1 ks2 k1 k2 x  y  z  q0  q1 q2  q3  n  omega  l] 
%y  [1     2    3    4  5  6  7   8    9   10  11 12   13   14]
% constant Omega len
function dsdy=maha4ode(s,y,para) % equation being solved

F=para(1);
gamma=para(2);
% Omega=lambda(1);
% len=lambda(2);

l11=y(8).^2 + y(9).^2 - y(10).^2 - y(11).^2;
l12=2.* (y(9).* y(10) + y(8).* y(11));
l13=2 .*(-y(8).* y(10) + y(9) .*y(11));
l21=2.* (y(9).* y(10) - y(8).* y(11));
l22=y(8).^2 - y(9).^2 + y(10).^2 - y(11).^2;
l23=2.* (y(8).* y(9) + y(10) .*y(11));
l31=2.* (y(8).* y(10) + y(9) .*y(11));
l32=2.* (-y(8) .*y(9) + y(10) .*y(11));
l33=y(8).^2 - y(9).^2 - y(10).^2 + y(11).^2;
dsdy=[
   y(14).^2.*(y(12).*y(3)+gamma.*l23+F.*gamma.*(y(3)-2.*y(13).*l13+y(13).^2.*(y(5).*l21+y(6).*l22)));
    y(14).^2.*(y(12).*y(4)-gamma.*l23+F.*gamma.*(y(4)-2.*y(13).*l23-y(13).^2.*(y(5).*l11+y(6).*l12)));
    y(1);
    y(2);
    2.*y(14).*(y(9).*y(11)+y(8).*y(10));
    2.*y(14).*(y(10).*y(11)+y(8).*y(9));
    y(14).*(-y(9).^2-y(10).^2+y(11).^2+y(8).^2);

    y(14)/2.*(-y(9).*y(3)-y(10).*y(4));
    y(14)/2.*(y(8).*y(3)-y(11).*y(4))+0+0+0+0+0;
    y(14)/2.*(y(11).*y(3)+y(8).*y(4));
    y(14)/2.*(-y(10).*y(3)+y(9).*y(4));
    -(y(3).*y(1)+y(4).*y(2))+y(14).*gamma.*(l33+F.*y(13).^2.*(y(5).*l31+y(6).*l32));
    0;
    0;
];
end
function res=maha4bc(ya,yb) %bounds 
res=[
    yb(5);
    yb(6);
    yb(7)-1;
    yb(9);
    yb(10);
    ya(8)-0.5;
    ya(9)+0.5;
    ya(10)-0.5;
    ya(11)-0.5;
    1/ya(5)-ya(13)
    ya(6);
    ya(7);
    ya(3)+ya(13);
    ya(4);
]
end
% y [ks1 ks2 k1 k2 x  y  z  q0  q1 q2  q3  n Omega len] 
%y  [1     2    3    4  5  6  7   8    9   10  11 12 13 14]
% constant Omega len
function yinit = maha4init(s) % initial guess function
% Omega=lambda(1);
% len=lambda(2);
% R=1/Omega;
p=2;
yinit = [
     0;                                                  %k1s                                                              
    0;                                                  %k2s               
   0;                                                       %k1                    
    -1;                                                  %k2         
    sin(p*pi/2.*s);                               %x                                             
    cos(p*pi/2.*s);                                                     %y                                            
    s;                                                  %z   
    0;                                                    %q0              
    -sin(pi/4.*(1-s));                              %q1                                       
   0;                                                %q2            
    cos(pi/4.*(1-s));                             %q3                                       
    0;                                                  %n      
    0.8;                                                  %Omega
    1.5;                                               %len
];
end
% define jacobi of ode and bounds

function jac=mahajac(s,y,para)
% Omega=lambda(1);
% len=lambda(2);
F=para(1);
gamma=para(2);
jac=[
0  0  F.*gamma + y(12).*y(14).^2  0  2.*F.*gamma.*y(13).^2.*(-(y(11).*y(8)) + y(10).*y(9))  F.*gamma.*y(13).^2.*(y(10).^2 - y(11).^2 + y(8).^2 - y(9).^2)  0  2.*gamma.*(F.*y(13).*(2.*y(10) - y(11).*y(13).*y(5) + y(13).*y(6).*y(8)) + y(9))  2.*gamma.*(y(8) + F.*y(13).*(-2.*y(11) + y(10).*y(13).*y(5) - y(13).*y(6).*y(9)))  2.*gamma.*(y(11) + F.*y(13).*(y(10).*y(13).*y(6) + 2.*y(8) + y(13).*y(5).*y(9)))  2.*gamma.*(y(10) - F.*y(13).*(y(11).*y(13).*y(6) + y(13).*y(5).*y(8) + 2.*y(9)))  y(14).^2.*y(3)  F.*gamma.*(4.*y(10).*y(8) - 4.*y(11).*y(9) + 4.*y(13).*y(5).*(-(y(11).*y(8)) + y(10).*y(9)) + 2.*y(13).*y(6).*(y(10).^2 - y(11).^2 + y(8).^2 - y(9).^2))  2.*y(12).*y(14).*y(3) 
0  0  0  F.*gamma + y(12).*y(14).^2  F.*gamma.*y(13).^2.*(y(10).^2 + y(11).^2 - y(8).^2 - y(9).^2)  -2.*F.*gamma.*y(13).^2.*(y(11).*y(8) + y(10).*y(9))  0  -2.*gamma.*(y(9) + F.*y(13).*(y(11).*y(13).*y(6) + y(13).*y(5).*y(8) + 2.*y(9)))  -2.*gamma.*(y(8) + F.*y(13).*(y(10).*y(13).*y(6) + 2.*y(8) + y(13).*y(5).*y(9)))  -2.*gamma.*(y(11) + 2.*F.*y(11).*y(13) + F.*y(13).^2.*(-(y(10).*y(5)) + y(6).*y(9)))  -2.*gamma.*(y(10) + 2.*F.*y(10).*y(13) + F.*y(13).^2.*(-(y(11).*y(5)) + y(6).*y(8)))  y(14).^2.*y(4)  F.*gamma.*(-4.*(y(10).*y(11) + y(8).*y(9)) - 2.*y(13).*(2.*y(6).*(y(11).*y(8) + y(10).*y(9)) + y(5).*(-y(10).^2 - y(11).^2 + y(8).^2 + y(9).^2)))  2.*y(12).*y(14).*y(4) 
1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  2.*y(10).*y(14)  2.*y(11).*y(14)  2.*y(14).*y(8)  2.*y(14).*y(9)  0  0  2.*(y(10).*y(8) + y(11).*y(9)) 
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  2.*y(14).*y(9)  2.*y(14).*y(8)  2.*y(11).*y(14)  2.*y(10).*y(14)  0  0  2.*(y(10).*y(11) + y(8).*y(9)) 
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  4.*y(14).*y(8)  -4.*y(14).*y(9)  -4.*y(10).*y(14)  4.*y(11).*y(14)  0  0  2.*(-y(10).^2 + y(11).^2 + y(8).^2 - y(9).^2) 
0  0  -1./2.*(y(14).*y(9))  -1./2.*(y(10).*y(14))  0  0  0  0  -1./2.*(y(14).*y(3))  -1./2.*(y(14).*y(4))  0  0  0  (-(y(10).*y(4)) - y(3).*y(9))./2 
0  0  (y(14).*y(8))./2  -1./2.*(y(11).*y(14))  0  0  0  (y(14).*y(3))./2  0  0  -1./2.*(y(14).*y(4))  0  0  (-(y(11).*y(4)) + y(3).*y(8))./2 
0  0  (y(11).*y(14))./2  (y(14).*y(8))./2  0  0  0  (y(14).*y(4))./2  0  0  (y(14).*y(3))./2  0  0  (y(11).*y(3) + y(4).*y(8))./2 
0  0  -1./2.*(y(10).*y(14))  (y(14).*y(9))./2  0  0  0  0  (y(14).*y(4))./2  -1./2.*(y(14).*y(3))  0  0  0  (-(y(10).*y(3)) + y(4).*y(9))./2 
-y(3)  -y(4)  -y(1)  -y(2)  2.*F.*gamma.*y(13).^2.*y(14).*(y(10).*y(8) + y(11).*y(9))  2.*F.*gamma.*y(13).^2.*y(14).*(y(10).*y(11) - y(8).*y(9))  0  2.*gamma.*y(14).*(y(8) + F.*y(13).^2.*(y(10).*y(5) - y(6).*y(9)))  gamma.*y(14).*(2.*F.*y(13).^2.*(y(11).*y(5) - y(6).*y(8)) - 2.*y(9))  gamma.*y(14).*(-2.*y(10) + 2.*F.*y(13).^2.*(y(11).*y(6) + y(5).*y(8)))  2.*gamma.*y(14).*(y(11) + F.*y(13).^2.*(y(10).*y(6) + y(5).*y(9)))  0  4.*F.*gamma.*y(13).*y(14).*(y(10).*y(11).*y(6) + y(10).*y(5).*y(8) + y(11).*y(5).*y(9) - y(6).*y(8).*y(9))  gamma.*(-y(10).^2 + y(11).^2 + y(8).^2 - y(9).^2 + 2.*F.*y(13).^2.*(y(10).*y(11).*y(6) + y(10).*y(5).*y(8) + y(11).*y(5).*y(9) - y(6).*y(8).*y(9))) 
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  
];
end


function [dBCdya dBCdyb]=mahabcjac(ya,yb,lambda)
dBCdya=[
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 0 0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 0 0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 0 0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 0 0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 0 0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0 0 0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0 0 0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0 0 0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0 0 0
0   0   0   0   -(1./ya(5).^2)  0   0   0   0   0   0   0 -1 0
0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0 0 0
0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0 0 0
0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 1 0
0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 0 0
];
dBCdyb=[
0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 0 0
0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0 0 0
0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0 0 0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0 0 0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0 0 0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 0 0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 0 0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 0 0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 0 0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 0 0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 0 0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 0 0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 0 0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 0 0
];
end
```

Another mathematica function I tried, with the the last example in this page (https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveBVP.html). Add $\Omega'(s)=0 \& l '(s)=0$ to the ODEs and use "shooting method", but it still fails.

```
Clear["`*"]
L = ({{q1[s]^2 - q2[s]^2 - q3[s]^2 + q0[s]^2, 
     2 (q1[s] q2[s] + q0[s] q3[s]), 
     2 (q1[s] q3[s] - q0[s] q2[s])}, {2 (q1[s] q2[s] - 
        q0[s] q3[s]), -q1[s]^2 + q2[s]^2 - q3[s]^2 + q0[s]^2, 
     2 (q2[s] q3[s] + q0[s] q1[s])}, {2 (q1[s] q3[s] + q0[s] q2[s]), 
     2 (q2[s] q3[s] - q0[s] q1[s]), -q1[s]^2 - q2[s]^2 + q3[s]^2 + 
      q0[s]^2}});
l11 = L[[1, 1]]; l12 = L[[1, 2]]; l13 = L[[1, 3]]; l21 = 
 L[[2, 1]]; l22 = L[[2, 2]]; l23 = L[[2, 3]]; l31 = L[[3, 1]]; l32 = 
 L[[3, 2]]; l33 = L[[3, 3]];
equ = {q1'[s] == l[s]/2 (q0[s] k1[s] - q3[s] k2[s]), 
   q2'[s] == l[s]/2 (q3[s] k1[s] + q0[s] k2[s]), 
   q3'[s] == l[s]/2 (-q2[s] k1[s] + q1[s] k2[s]), 
   q0'[s] == l[s]/2 (-q1[s] k1[s] - q2[s] k2[s]), 
   x'[s] == 2 *l[s]*(q1[s] q3[s] + q0[s] q2[s]), 
   y'[s] == 2 *l[s]*(q2[s] q3[s] + q0[s] q1[s]), 
   z'[s] == l [s] (-q1[s]^2 - q2[s]^2 + q3[s]^2 + q0[s]^2), 
   n'[s] == -(k1[s]*k1'[s] + k2[s]*k2'[s]) + 
     l[s] *γ*(l33 + F*Om[s]^2*(x[s]*l31 + y[s]*l32)), 
   k1''[s] == 
    l[s]^2 (n[s]*k1[s] + γ*l23 + 
       F*γ*(k1[s] - 2*Om[s]*l13 + 
          Om[s]^2*(x[s]*l21 + y[s]*l22))), 
   k2''[s] == 
    l[s]^2 (n[s]*k2[s] - γ*l23 + 
       F*γ*(k2[s] - 2*Om[s]*l23 - 
          Om[s]^2*(x[s]*l11 + y[s]*l12))),
   Om'[s] == 0, l'[s] == 0};
bound = {x[1] == 0, y[1] == 0, z[1] == 1, q1[1] == 0, q2[1] == 0, 
   q1[0] == -0.5, q2[0] == 0.5, q3[0] == 0.5, q0[0] == 0.5, y[0] == 0,
    z[0] == 0, k2[0] == 0, k1[0]*x[0] == -1, Om[0] *x[0] == 1};
Length[bound]
Length[equ]
F = 0.1; γ = 10;
x0 = 0.5;
Om0 = 0.8;
l0 = 1.5;
sol = NDSolve[
   equ~Join~bound, {x, y, z, q0, q1, q2, q3, n, k1, k2, Om, l}, {s, 0,
     1}, Method -> {"Shooting", 
     "StartingInitialConditions" -> {q1[0] == -0.5, q2[0] == 0.5, 
       q3[0] == 0.5, q0[0] == 0.5, y[0] == 0, z[0] == 0, k2[0] == 0, 
       k1[0] == -Om0, Om[0] == Om0, x[0] == x0, n[0] == 0.8, 
       l[0] == l0}}, MaxSteps -> 10000];
```

Comment: Check the document of `ParametricNDSolveValue`

Comment: I have tried, but the tolerance maybe not enough.

Comment: @JiahaoLi Why not to use a continuation or homotopy method as they recommended in the paper?

Comment: I have tried in matlab with continuation method but It fails.

Answer (score 3):

"Shooting" is central to the two Mathematica code blocks in the question, and "Shooting" often requires good "StartingInitialConditions".  Lacking that, I tried minimizing the difference between the desired and computed boundary values at `s = 1`.  With `equ` and `bound` as in the first code block of the question, define

```
f = ParametricNDSolveValue[{equ, bound[[4 ;;]], 
    {n[0] == ns, k1'[0] == k1ps, k2'[0] == k2ps}}, 
    Norm[{x[1], y[1], z[1] - 1, q1[1], q2[1]}], {s, 0, 1}, 
    {Ω, l, ns, k1ps, k2ps}];

NMinimize[{f[Ω, l, ns, k1ps, k2ps], Ω > 0, l > 0}, {Ω, l, ns, k1ps, k2ps}]
(* {0.0754877, {Ω -> 0.350903, l -> 5.65041, 
    ns -> 0.834975, k1ps -> 1.16113, k2ps -> -0.0412428}} *)
```

I had hoped for a minimum value of order 10^-7 instead of 0.075. So, I tried each of the five non-convex methods for `NMinimize`, but with essentially the same results.  `FindMinimum` did no better.

**Addendum: `WorkingPrecision -> 30`**

Subsequently, I tried increasing the `WorkingPrecision` to `30` in `ParametricNDSolveValue` and `NMinimize`.  (Rationalizing all decimal quantities is required for consistency.)  Several hours of calculation, yielded

```
(* {0.0627944873467107037643904573410, {Ω -> 0.226553484599600442327014225650,
 l -> 8.56446128690867501588409483064, ns -> 0.963290814886147200831448603970, 
 k1ps -> 1.28697954280560113915153879654, 
 k2ps -> -0.00336812742469050102203450750230}} *}
```

which increased `l` from 5.65 to 8.23 and decreased `Ω` from 0.35 to 0.23, while reducing the `s = 1` residual error from .075 to .063.  Presumably, higher `WorkingPrecision` would produce better results but at prohibitive computation cost.

Here are plots of the solution.

```
splt = NDSolveValue[{equ, bound[[4 ;;]], {n[0] == ns, k1'[0] == 
    k1ps, k2'[0] == k2ps}} /. Last[%], {x, y, z, q0, q1, q2, q3, n, k1, k2}, 
    {s, 0, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 30];

Plot[Evaluate@Through[splt[[;; 3]][s]], {s, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All, 
    PlotLegends -> Placed[{x, y, z}, {.12, .6}], ImageSize -> Large, 
    LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[Evaluate@Through[splt[[4 ;; 7]][s]], {s, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All,
    PlotLegends -> Placed[{q0, q1, q2, q3}, {.12, .6}], ImageSize -> Large, 
    LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[Evaluate@Through[splt[[8 ;;]][s]], {s, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All, 
    PlotLegends -> Placed[{n, k1, k2}, {.12, .8}], ImageSize -> Large, 
    LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}]
```

[image]

If the OP provides the solution obtained in the cited article, I would be happy to attempt to reproduce it.